# drop down list triggers manipulation fail vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create drop down list using vba which would trigger a series of actions (data manipulation) but it seems like something is wrong with me code where it would crash every time I run it so I can't tell what error I m getting, if any.

I have tried to use new file so it can open and close, not the corrupted file. My drop down list is a named range from another tab called territory which I have 8 territories. In my data sheet, in column B I have a list of all counties in Florida and column A is the corresponding territory. I am trying to write macros that can delete rows for which counties that aren't in the territory of the selection. So if user selects West Central, the rows will only show counties that are in West Central Territory. Cell B3 is a merged cell (B3 to N3) but I am not sure if it is the reason why it is not working.

I have tried "--Select--" and "Florida" options from my drop down list and they all work fine. I am only listing one territory since this is the first one that I got to and my code is already not working. I have included my workbook and my vba environment so just in case you want to check that.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Dim TT As Worksheet

Set TT = Worksheets("Territory Tool")

Select Case Range("B3")
Case "--Select--"
TT.Rows("9:76").EntireRow.Hidden = True

Case "Florida"
TT.Rows("9:76").EntireRow.Hidden = False


Case "West Central"
TT.Range("A76:A83") = "West Central"


'filter
Dim Rng As Range
Dim x, LR1, LR2 As Long
Set Rng = TT.Range("A9:A83")
For x = Rng.Rows.Count To 9 Step -1
If InStr(1, Rng.Cells(x, 1).Text, "West Central") = 0 Then
Rng.Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next x

End Select

End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: if you want to use the `worksheet_change` event, the code has to be in the sheet that you want to watch not in `ThisWorkbook`. Also you should specify the worksheet for the `select case`.

Comment: Also another [example](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/213612/how-to-run-a-macro-when-certain-cells-change-in-excel), if you just want to run the code if certain cells change.

Answer (score 0):

When handling change events at the workbook level you first need to check that `Sh` is the worksheet you're interested in, and then be sure to scope all range references to the sheet where the event occurred.

Untested:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim r As Range
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim x, LR1, LR2 As Long

    'is this the sheet we're checking for changes?
    If Sh.Name <> "Territory Tool" Then Exit Sub

    'did a change occur in the range of interest?
    Set r = Application.Intersect(Target, Sh.Range("B3"))

    If r Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'exit if B3 not changed...

    Select Case r.Value
        Case "--Select--"
            Sh.Rows("9:76").EntireRow.Hidden = True

        Case "Florida"
            Sh.Rows("9:76").EntireRow.Hidden = False

        Case "West Central"
            Sh.Range("A76:A83") = "West Central"

            'filter
            Set Rng = Sh.Range("A9:A83")
            For x = Rng.Rows.Count To 9 Step -1
                If InStr(1, Rng.Cells(x, 1).Text, "West Central") = 0 Then
                    Rng.Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            Next x

    End Select

End Sub
```